# How to hide a label for a field with a null value using Thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I'm using Thymeleaf as template engine for a Spring application, and I would like to hide its label, when a field has a null value. This is my approach, that I haven't managed to make it work:

```
<div th:if="${booking.privatecomments}">
     <b th:text="#{booking.private.comments}"></b>
     <p th:utext="${booking.privatecomments}"></p>
</div>
```

The label is the second line.

I've tried this different approach, but without success either:

```
<div th:utext="${booking.privatecomments != null}? 
     #{booking.private.comments} + ': ' + ${booking.privatecomments}"></div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that your problem is either in the return type of `privatecomments` (it is string, isn't it?) or that it is simply not null (e.g. empty).

Nevertheless if you want to hide a fragment `th:if` or its counterpart `th:unless` are the way to go. Here is how `th:if` works. Once you get it it will be trivial to resolve your problem.

It will evaluate to `true` in the following cases:

If passed value is not null:

- If value is a boolean and is true
- If value is a number and is non-zero
- If value is a character and is non-zero
- If value is a string and is not "false", "off" or "no"
- If value is not a boolean, a number, a character or a String.

If value is `null`, `th:if` will always evaluate to false.

You may find the complete documentation with examples [here](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#simple-conditionals-if-and-unless). I would recommend that you provide a boolean property on the booking object that will answer if there are private comments.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I didn't realize that the fields were empty, instead of null. I took for granted, that it was the same.